# why my single threaded java program is consuming more than max heap size?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I have created a simple java program :-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class OOMError {

    public static List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Process Id: "+ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName());
        try{
            while(true){
                List<Person> innerList = new ArrayList<>();

                for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
                    list.add(new Person());
                }

                int count = 0;

                while(count < 60){
                    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
                        innerList.add(new Person());
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000*60);
                    count=count+5;
                }

                Thread.sleep(1000*60*10);

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static class Person{
        private String fName ;
        private String lName;

        Person(){
            fName = new String("Stack");
            lName = new String("Overflow");
        }
    }
}
```

I ran this program with **export JAVA_OPTS='-Xms128m -Xmx1024m'**

and i am monitoring my java application RAM usage by top command.

```
Processes: 94 total, 10 running, 2 stuck, 82 sleeping, 2765 threads                                                                                           06:59:51
Load Avg: 2.62, 2.74, 2.68  CPU usage: 0.11% user, 0.54% sys, 99.33% idle  SharedLibs: 13M resident, 25M data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 28079 total, 19G resident, 24M private, 3449M shared. PhysMem: 2776M wired, 19G active, 3718M inactive, 25G used, 39G free.
VM: 605G vsize, 1199M framework vsize, 118994555(0) pageins, 0(0) pageouts. Networks: packets: 80924129/10G in, 112346940/77G out.
Disks: 4011149/367G read, 9149138/634G written.

PID    COMMAND      %CPU   TIME     #TH   #WQ  #POR #MRE RPRVT  RSHR RSIZE  VPRVT  VSIZ PGRP  PPID  STATE   UID  FAULTS  COW  MSGS MSGR SYSBSD  SYSMACH CSW     PAGE
89038  java         0.0    02:01.65 31    2    112  437  1237M  10M  1251M  2101M  19G  89038 88799 stuck   501  321189  448  651  300  250145+ 358994  304415+ 0
```

I am surprised how can i my RSIZE field is 1251M when my max heap size is 1024M and the state is coming as "stuck" ?

What will happen once my heap is full ? Will the application terminate ?

I am using OS X 10.X.X

Comment: Well, not everything is in the heap. Memory is also used by the stack to hold method calls, their parameters and local variables. And memory is also consumed to hold the bytecode of the loaded classes.

Comment: May be you forgot 'set' after 'export'?

Comment: Basically the heap size allocated by Xmx isn't the whole of the memory used by Java. There's also the JVM itself - and possibly JITted classes, etc.

Comment: Please put it in answer and also what does state=stuck means ? since JVM is already max to its heap size it has stuck the java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JRockit Blog there is an article that explains this:

> The command line argument `-Xmx` sets the maximum Java heap size (mx).
>   All java objects are created on the Java heap, but the total memory
>   consumption of the JVM process consist of more things than just the
>   Java heap. A few examples:
>
> - Generated (JIT:ed) code
> - Loaded libraries (including jar and class files)
> - Control structures for the java heap
> - Thread Stacks
> - User native memory (malloc:ed in JNI)

Source: [Why is my JVM process larger than max heap size?](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrockit/entry/why_is_my_jvm_process_larger_t)

Comment: Please tell me that how can i figure out the heap used by my process through command line and not using jconsole actually i am doing ssh to another box , so jconsole will not work for me.

Comment: You can use `jstat -gc pid`. Check out [jstat Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html) for output format and examples.